# How do I make the instagram login in my app, connected through auth0?

Tags: facebook, ionic3, facebook-login, instagram-api, auth0

I'm developing a mobile app in Ionic3, that is connected with auth0, to login with instagram, but I cannot find the correct credentials (client id, and client secret) to get that working properly. I need help because old Instagram API is no longer reviewing apps, I really don't know what to do.

I've already tried searching and connecting with all the credentials that New facebook developer dashboard gave me, but no one works. Also I have created the app in Facebook dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can find both your `Client ID` and `Client Secret` within your application's setting tab within your Auth0 Dashboard.

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials

<sub>(Affiliation: I'm Community Lead at Auth0.)</sub>